# Duplicate primary key in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do an invoice for customers who bought products. I want same `ID_Invoice` and inside there will be different products that customer bought.

I want it to looks like this,

```
|ID_Invoice | ID_Reg | ID_Product | ProductType | Price |
+-----------+--------+------------+-------------+-------+
|    1      |   1    |  12345     |  Software   |  300  |
|    1      |   1    |  12346     |  Software   |  400  |
|    2      |   3    |  12347     |  Software   |  350  |
|    3      |   4    |  22346     |  Hardware   |  600  |
```

The same customer (`ID_Reg`) can buy 2 different products and it will be in same invoice (`ID_Invoice`).

But when I try to insert values into `Invoice` I get an error

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_IDInvoice'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Invoice'. The duplicate key value is (1).

I hope I explained well

Comment: Your invoice table doesn't allow such duplicates.  Sounds like you need two tables to me.

Comment: Can you explain me more? In two tables there will be which columns?

Comment: Go look at the standard MS sample databases to see how "sales" or "invoices" are typically database. You usually need at least 2 tables to support this sort of information. Just like a receipt you receive when you make purchase at a store, an invoice is really just a collection of one or more things you buy (or sell). Designing databases is a very different skill than writing code to use a database. I suggest you find a well-designed database first if you are just learning to code

Comment: Thank you so much for the helps! I ended up with making two tables one is connecting to customer and other one is connecting to products. This was a school project that at the same time we have to create a database then dml for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an `invoices` table where each row represents a single invoice and the `id_invoice` is the primary key.

You want an `invoice_lines` or `invoice_products` table that has one row per invoice line (or product).  That is basically the table you have described above.

Given your description, the `(id_invoice, id_product)` should be unique in this table.  And `id_invoice` should be a foreign key reference to `invoices(id_invoice)`.  I would generally give such a table an `identity` primary key as well.

Comment: dtaskin that answer does not solve your problem ?